# Print a list of BAPIs using JCo

Tags: java, jco, bapi, sapjco3

I established connection to a SAP Server and I would like to print a list of BAPIs in my Java program. I am using sapjco3.jar.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no "BAPI to get a list of BAPIs", so this would be a non-trivial task. You could try to use `RFC_FUNCTION_SEARCH` to search for function modules named `BAPI*`, but that's not guaranteed to give you a) only official BAPIs and b) all of the official BAPIs...

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the function module `SWO_QUERY_API_METHODS`. The following code snippet works with JCo 2:

```
IFunctionTemplate functionTemplate = Repository.getFunctionTemplate("SWO_QUERY_API_METHODS");
JCO.Function function = functionTemplate.getFunction();
mConnection.execute(function);

ParameterList exportParameter = function.getExportParameterList();
System.out.println("exportParameter: " + exportParameter);
ParameterList importParameter = function.getImportParameterList();
System.out.println("importParameter: " + importParameter);
ParameterList tableParameter = function.getTableParameterList();
System.out.println("tableParameter: " + tableParameter);
```

Comment: Be aware that `SWO_QUERY_API_METHODS` is not a BAPI, it's just a RFC-enabled function module that was released for internal use. It may change or disappear without a warning to customers. Other than that, this sounds like a great alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the BAPI_MONITOR_GETLIST to get a list of all BAPIs in your system together with meta data.

Answer (score 2):

You could make an ABAP function  searching for all RFC functions in table TFDIR, with FMODE ='R' (remote). However, This will give you all remote-callable function, not only BAPIs.