# Get available BAPIs and/or tables

Tags: c#, bapi, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-data-dictionary

I have developed a component in C# 2010 using SAP .NET Connector 3.0 to run BAPI Modules and read SAP tables data and schemas.

Is there a BAPI (or some other way) to get:

1. list of available tables
2. list of available BAPIs

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SAP and sapjco3 print a list of BAPIs in my java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463182/sap-and-sapjco3-print-a-list-of-bapis-in-my-java-program)

Comment: You're right, the topic reported has helped me to get the list of BAPI. Now I'd like to undestand how to get the list of tables. Thanks

Comment: you could read table DD02L to get the tables in the system.

Comment: Thak you Dirk. It works!

Answer (score 0):

- Existing RFC to load the SAP Table data is [RFC_READ_TABLE](https://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/func/rfc_read_table.html) (External access to R/3 tables via RFC)

Answer (score 0):

For reading list of tables as correctly suggested by Dirk you can use table `DD02L`, it contains all tables in the system.

For reading all BAPIs in the system you can use module `BAPI_MONITOR_GETLIST`.