# Is BAPI_MATERIAL_GET_ALL a BAPI, or just a RFC?

Tags: sap-erp, saprfc, bapi

I am using SWO_QUERY_API_METHODS to get list of BAPIs in the SAP system. But I am not getting BAPI_MATERIAL_GET_ALL, CSEP_MAT_BOM_READ and potentially others in that list.
Is BAPI_MATERIAL_GET_ALL a BAPI or just a RFC ?

Comment: I guess you are querying the "standardized BAPIs", they have to exist in transaction code `SWO1` (also listed in transaction code `BAPI`). The term "BAPI" is not very clear to be honest, there's the theory (SAP official documentation), and there are the beliefs (the real world in fact). Lots of people say "BAPI" for anything starting with the name "BAPI". Lots of people think that they can use all BAPIs. I think that even BAPI doesn't mean a function module in all cases... Concerning RFC, it's easy to check if a function module is RFC-enabled.

Comment: consider also this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463182/print-a-list-of-bapis-using-jco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely a BAPI because it resides in function group named by business object `BUS1001006` **Standard Material**

[image]

But I agree with Sandra this definition is very blurry as it was created long-long ago and is used hither and yon.

Use this module with version specification of when the BAPI was created. Depending on version the output varies.

```
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_MONITOR_GETLIST'
 EXPORTING
   SHOW_RELEASE            = '620'
 TABLES
   BAPILIST                = api
 .
```

Where to get version? Of course, by finding the module in BAPI transaction in the BUS1001006 section

[image]

Moreover, for your total confusion there are two different BAPIs almost identical in names: **BAPI_MATERIAL_GETALL** and **BAPI_MATERIAL_GET_ALL**, one older and one yonger, and the first marked as a wrapper for the latter.

It is a usual situation when SAP decided to revamp the API and left old stuff for legacy.

[image]

So yes, things are complicated. It is always with SAP.

Comment: I can see BAPI_MATERIAL_GETALL in the list and it is also present in BAPI explorer as you show in the answer. My confusion was about BAPI_MATERIAL_GET_ALL. But as you mention this is probably the older/legacy one which is supported but no longer part of official/released BAPIs.

Comment: yes, outdated BAPIs are usually excluded from the catalog